# Problema de sintáxis en sql server

Tags: sql

Quiero crear una vista con este statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW prueba  as select * from company.alarma
```

pero dice que hay error de sintáxis.Cual es el problema?
**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.**

Comment: Company.alarma? Alarma es un campo de la tabla Company?

Comment: company es un esquema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se solucionó así:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW {nombre} AS  {select statement} as {un nombrecualquiera};
```

Comment: Como comentario adicional, este comando solo funciona a partir de la versión 2016 SP1. Esto es por si a alguien le marca error al querer usarlo.